# divide into seperate columns and calculate the average

Tags: r, excel, division

Can you help me do this coding please?
I have a column of data (100,000 rows) in Excel and I want to divide it into 100 columns of 1000 rows. And after that I want to calculate the average of each 5 rows in a new excel file.

Thanks.

```
1   12   67.8
2   154  450.2
3   16   220
4   0   
5   157 
6   1   
7   32  
8   21  
9   2143    
10  54  
11  2   
12  32  
13  45  
14  985 
15  36
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where is the problem, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option to create a `matrix` from the column of interest by specifying the `nrow` and `ncol`, then `split` the `matrix` with a grouping index created with `gl` into 5 rows each, loop through the `list` with `sapply` and get the column means

```
m1 <- matrix(df1$Column, ncol = 100, nrow = 1000)
sapply(split(seq_len(nrow(m1)), as.integer(gl(nrow(m1), 5,
        nrow(m1)))), function(i) colMeans(m1[i, ]))
```